# modifying css with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a ul list and below im using jquery to find out if the user is hovering sub menus under about us and if yes set some css on hover.  This does change the background color to green but when i hover off the green doesnt go away?

JQUERY

```
$('ul > li > ul > li a').hover(
    function(){
        var whatami = $(this).parents('li').eq(1).find('a[title]:first').attr('title');
        console.log(whatami);
        if (whatami == 'About Us') {
            //alert(whatami);
            $('.white ul.mega-menu li .sub-container.non-mega li a:hover').css({"background-color":"green"});

        }
    },
    function(){
    });
```

Comment: give your html code on jsfiddle please.

Comment: Why not add a class to the 'about us' menu and make a css rule specific to it? a.green:hover { background-color: green; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in jQuery the :hover is just an element selector, it's not the same as CSS a:hover. Trying something like:

```
$('.white ul.mega-menu li .sub-container.non-mega li a').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).css({"background-color":"green"});
    },
    function () {
        $(this).css({"background-color":"none"});
    }
); ​
```

Answer (score 3):

The way hover works is that the first function is executed when the mouse enters and the 2nd is executed when the mouse leaves.  You have nothing in the 2nd function, so that means nothing will happen when the mouse leaves.  You need to do whatever you want to do in the 2nd function:

```
$('ul > li > ul > li a').hover(
function(){
    // make it green
},
function(){
    // CHANGE IT BACK HERE
});
```

Comment: One optimization (of many) worth nothing is that you can replace `.parents('li').eq(1)` with `.closest('li')`.  JQuery has a function for that.  Posting in a comment as it is not related to the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

`.white ul.mega-menu li .sub-container.non-mega li a` is what you should be using as a your selector, your current selector `ul > li > ul > li a` is more generalized.

Try to use either `$(this)` for setting the green